# Python quit() function returns error. I am using spyder 4.1.2

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

```
file = input("Enter file name:")
try:
   fhand = open(file,'r')
except:
    print("File not found")
    quit() # Error: name 'quit' is not defined


count = 0
for line in fhand:
    line =line.strip()
    if line.startswith('Subject'):
       count+=1
print('There were,',count,'subject lines in ',file)
```

This error should not occur. I am confused to heights what am I doing wrong here. i get the error **'name 'quit' is not defined'**. Which should not come.

Comment: I think you mean `exit()`?

Comment: @MoonCheesez quit(), exit(), sys.exit() and os._exit(), all should work. but none of them work. same error appears always. This is a very weird behavior.

Comment: @MoonCheesez I just checked it with Python IDE. The code runs flawlessly there. But with anaconda/Spyder this error surfaces.

Comment: Keep your posted code _small_. You do not need the second part of it to asl your question. The shorter is the fragment, the easier it is to spot the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quit()` and `exit()` rely on the `site` module, and, to my knowledge, they're designed for being used in interactive mode and not in actual programs or production code.

Instead, I'd recommend making your program look more like this:

```
file = input("Enter file name:")
try:
    fhand = open(file,'r')
    count = 0
    for line in fhand:
        line =line.strip()
        if line.startswith('Subject'):
           count+=1
    fhand.close()
    print('There were,',count,'subject lines in ',file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
```

You also may want to read the file immediately and close it sooner.